# How can i mount my galaxy s4 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, samsung

this is the error message i get when i plug my S4 into the usb port:

```
Error initializing camera: -1: Unspecified error
```

how can i correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 13.04.

Android has moved away from supporting USB mass storage mode, whereby the phone looks like a USB disk drive, and now requires the use of the MTP protocol to transfer files.  This wasn't properly supported in 12.04, but is in 13.04.

Comment: @AndrewBeals, on 13.04?  I used to get that error before 13.04 but now it works for me.